# Run Powershell commands sequentially in their own windows and prevent them from exiting

Tags: powershell

I want to run multiple Powershell commands sequentially in their own Powershell windows and do not want those windows to be closed after running.

**Example:**

```
Start-Process powershell {Write-Host "hello"}; Start-Process powershell 
{Write-Host "hello"}; Start-Process powershell {Write-Host "hello"}
```

Powershell windows get closed right after running. I want them to remain open.

**Edit:** Multiple commands are not always same and they may vary in number.

Comment: `Get-Help -Name Start-Process -Parameter NoNewWindow` or, `powershell.exe -?`

Answer (score 3):

```
# Asynchronously starts 3 new PowerShell windows that 
# print "hello #<n>" to the console and stay open.
1..3 | ForEach-Object { 
  Start-Process powershell -Args '-noexit', '-command', "Write-Host 'hello #$_'" 
}
```

- `-noexit` is required to keep a PowerShell session open after executing a command with `-command` (run `powershell.exe -?` to see all CLI parameters)
- Note how the arguments are specified *individually*, as `,`-separated elements of an *array* that is passed to
  `-Args` (short for `-ArgumentList`, though the parameter name can be omitted altogether in this case).
- Note how the `Write-Host` command is passed as a *string* - script blocks aren't supported as such in this scenario; you can pass one, as you tried, but it will be quietly converted to a *string*, which simply means that its *literal content* is used (everything between `{` and `}`).
  In other words: passing `{Write-Host "hello"}` is the same as `'Write-Host "hello"'`, but to avoid confusion you should pass a *string*.

  - You can only pass a script block as such if you invoke `powershell.exe` *directly*, not via `Start-Process`; you need `Start-Process`, however, to run the new session in a new window and to start it *asynchronously*.
  - Also, the string was changed to a *double-quoted* string (`"..."`) with embedded *single-quoting* (`'...'`) to ensure that the reference to `$_` - the automatic variable representing the pipeline object at hand (`1`, `2`, or `3`) - is *expanded* (interpolated).

Using the *pipeline* (`|`) with an array of inputs (`1..3`, which evaluates to array `1, 2, 3`) with the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet is just an example - **you can still invoke the individual commands individually, one after the other**, on individual lines, or separated with `;` - thanks to `Start-Process` they'll still launch asynchronously.

However, if the individual commands *share logic*, the pipeline approach can simplify matters; you can put the shared logic in the body of the `ForEach-Object` call and pass the variable parts as input via the pipeline.

Comment: multiple commands are not always same and they may vary in number.

Comment: @Faheem: The loop was obviously just an example (that took the repetitiveness out of your code). You can invoke individual, customized `Start-Process` calls one after the other, or pass in arguments to the `%` (`ForEach-Object`) loop to vary the commands that way; `$_` inside the script block (`{ ... }`) then refers to the argument at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Put a read-host at the end of the command sequence - it will wait for you to input something before continuing execution (and presumably exiting?). To copy/paste the example in this link, you could anything like this which will pause execution until you enter something: `$Age = Read-Host "Please enter your age"` -> Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host?view=powershell-6